# Flash on top of normal HTML

Tags: html, flash, overlay

In our web application we are planning to develop the Top Navigation in Flex and the page content in normal HTML.On hover over the menus of top nav, the child nodes are shown. The childrens should be shown on top of the HTML content. So what should be the height of the top navigation SWF file for the overlay to work properly. 
Initilly the top navigation's height will be say 40 px. On hover it will be say 200px.ie the swf file's height should be 200px? If that is the case initially (not hover) there will be some empty space between the top nav and html content. Or should I use some CSS in the HTMl content to over come this? 
Please provide some ideas on implementing this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

THanks,
Jish

Answer (score 0):

If you make the SWF 200px and just sit it in a div above your page content then you're right, you'll have a gap when the menu isn't showing dropdown items.

I would imagine your best solution would be to place your swf content in a 200px div with a high z-index.  Depending on what your site content is you might then put it in a container div with an absolute position that places it 40 px from the page top.  With a transparent SWF background this should work... BUT from what I understand there are rendering problems with overlaid transparent SWFs in older versions of FF and maybe others.  Usually I've seen this discussed with relation to floating an ad over the page and the workaround for uncooperative browsers is just to redirect to a page without the ad, but that won't work with your menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. I have one question regarding this, if the SWF's background is transparent and if it is at a higer z-index than HTML, will the user be able to select the text behind the SWF?

Comment: No, if the z-index is higher the user will only be able to select the swf, not the underlying text.